# wallpapermanager, Image doesn't fit to the screen size.what to do?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which, there is an option to set as wallpaper in each screen.(Each screen has different images.) The problem is when I press set as wallpaper option , the image doesn't fit properly to the screen size. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
wbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
               "Wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
     = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
     myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.two);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please suggest modification to the code so that i can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
wbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
      try {
        myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.two);
        myWallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(w, h);
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
});
```

**And remember to add permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```